# Efficient way to check if a getter will return null in Java before passing to Optional?

Tags: java, optional-chaining

I have a simple data class such as

```
@Data
@Builder
public class MyPerson implements Serializable {
    String name;
    String age; //Purposely keeping as String here
    String address;
}
```

After constructing the object, I want to construct an Immutable object using it with the following definition, where I know name will never be null, but age and address might:

```
@Value.Style(stagedBuilder = true)
@Value.Immutable
public interface MyImmutablePerson extends Serializable {
    String getName();
    Optional<Integer> getAge();
    Optional<String> getAddress();
}
```

The first person object is created, and now want to create this second Immutable object, where age and address could be null

```
MyImmutablePerson.builder()
    .name(myPerson.getName())
    .age(myPerson.getAge()) //Could be null!
    .address(myPerson.getAddress()) //Could be null!
    .build()
```

My thought it is that I could pass to another function to check and return an empty optional if it is null:

```
private Optional<Integer> checkNullAge(String age) {
    if (age.isNull()) {
        return Optional.empty()
    }
    
    return Optional.of(age);
}
```

In doing this, I have duplicate another class just for Strings, another class for Boolean,.... etc. which is super ineficient.

Is there a better way to do a null check and then return an empty optional?

Comment: Just use `builder().age(Optional.ofNullable(myPerson.getAge()))` etc

Comment: hmm this returns an error `Cannot resolve method 'age(Optional<T>)'`, and trying to cast it to an Optional<Integer> says that it's an inconvertible type

Comment: Make MyImmutablePerson a class and add @Builder? Or make it a `record`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`return` [`Optional.ofNullable(age)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html#ofNullable(T))`;`!?;)

> Returns an Optional describing the given value, if non-null, otherwise returns an empty Optional.

For "conversion" (String->Integer) [@bro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16320675/user16320675) proposed [`Optional.map()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html#map(java.util.function.Function))!(thx!)
Which...

> If a value is present, returns an `Optional` describing (as if by `ofNullable(T)`) the result of applying the given mapping function to the value, otherwise returns an empty `Optional`.

So that we can finally:

```
private /*static*/ Optional<Integer> checkNullAge(String age) {
    // try {
    
    return Optional.ofNullable(age).map(Integer::valueOf);
    // } catch (NumberFormatException nfE) ...
}
```

Comment: Should be `==` actually >.< The best I've come up with is 
`private Optional<Integer> checkNullAge(String age) {
        if (age == null) {
            return Optional.empty();
        }

        return Optional.of(Integer.valueOf(age));
    }
`
To do the Integer conversion.

Comment: In not null/any case you could also encounter "number format exception" ...but (maybe) better "overall" approach: make it (possibly) same data type, (technically)nullable, but with  "validation"...

Comment: `Optional` also has a [`map()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html#map(java.util.function.Function)) method: `Optional.ofNullable(age).map(Integer::valueOf)`

Comment: @xerx593 just saw your revision. Thank you, this is it!